# Cannot find where a redirect is specified

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've recently become the maintainer of a Wordpress site (I'm completely new to wordpress) and I'm having some difficulty determining where a redirect is specified.

I've checked the `.htaccess` file, and there's nothing specified in there.  As far as I can tell, the rewrite rules aren't the cause.

I've tried deleting the page being redirected from and re-creating it, and the redirect still occurs.

My question is: where can you specify a redirect?  I've run out of ideas of where to look.

Comment: what exactly is the issue? Question is not that much clear.

Comment: As with regular php you can specify a redirect anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

one of my client want to custom url like

**https://www.qsleap.com/gmat/resources**  as you know in wordpress evry request is catch by index.php . request filter catches the request and 
call the page .

Read this code it may give you any idea.

```
 function permalinks_customizer_request_before($query ){
$uri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$match= preg_match('/(gmat|gre|sat|lsat|cat)(\/resources\/tags\/)
(.*)\/(articles|videos|concept-notes|qna)/', $uri,$matches);
//$match= 
preg_match('/(gmat|gre|sat|lsat|cat)/\resources/\tags/stanford-
gsb/\articles|videos|concept-notes)/?$', $uri,$matches);
if($match){

    $url = parse_url( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );
    $url = isset( $url['path'])  ? $url['path'] : '';
  $request = ltrim( substr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen( $url ) ), '/' );
    $request = ( ( $pos = strpos( $request, '?' ) ) ? substr( $request, 0, $pos ) : $request );
    if ( ! $request )
        return $query;
    $original_url="?page_name=tags&exam=".$matches[1]."&post_tag=".$matches[3]."&post_type=".$matches[4];
    if ( $original_url !== null ) {
        $original_url = str_replace('//', '/', $original_url);
        if ( ( $pos = strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' ) ) !== false ) {
            $queryVars = substr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $pos + 1 );
            $original_url .= ( strpos( $original_url, '?' ) === false ? '?' : '&') . $queryVars;
        }
        $oldRequestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $oldQueryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/' . ltrim( $original_url, '/' );
        $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = ( ( $pos = strpos( $original_url, '?' ) ) !== false ? substr( $original_url, $pos + 1 ) : '' );

        parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queryArray );
        $oldValues = array();
        global $wp;
        $wp->parse_request();
        $query = $wp->query_vars;
        if ( is_array( $queryArray ) ) {
                foreach ( $queryArray as $key => $value ) {
                        $oldValues[$key] = $_REQUEST[$key];
                        $_REQUEST[$key] = $_GET[$key] = $value;
                        $query[$key]=$value;
                }
        }
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ='';
        $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']='';
    }


 }
 return $query;
 }


 add_filter( 'request','permalinks_customizer_request_before',0);
 function wp_url_rewrite_templates() {
     if (get_query_var( 'page_name' ) && get_query_var( 'page_name' 
   )=='tags') {
    add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
        $template= dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/page-tags.php';
        return $template;

    });
}


  }
  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_url_rewrite_templates' ,4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way for you to remove the redirects will be with this plugin.

https://redirection.me/

After you install it and activate it. From the Wordpress Admin

> Tools > Redirection

You'll see a list of redirects, and add/remove any.